# Facebook sharing photo not working Meta data problem

Tags: android

What is the meaning of this error

```
    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"

Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId@value value=(@string/facebook_app_id) from AndroidManifest.xml:56:13-52
    is also present at [com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.3.1] AndroidManifest.xml:21:13-60 value=(@string/facebook_application_id).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to <meta-data> element at AndroidManifest.xml:55:9-57:15 to override.
```

Comment: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/1026

Answer (score 0):

I checked the issue and this may help you out:
In your `AndroidManifest.xml` remove:

```
   <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />
```

Hope this helps.
Reference:
https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/1026#issuecomment-412992715